# Moving a domain name - with Google Apps - to another registrar

Tags: domain, g-suite, domain-registrar

I'm intending to move my primary domain registration from its current location (my web host) to a separate registrar. Not because there's a problem with the current setup, but rather to have my domains all in one place. The web hosting is staying put (for now, anyway), it's just the domain registration being changed.

I've moved domain names around before, and know about changing the nameserver information to match wherever the site is hosted. The catch here is that I am using Google Apps for my domain. I'm aware there's some special setup to make that work, though I don't know the details. The host handled these details in the initial setup.

Are there extra steps involved in making Google Apps work with the domain when the domain name is moved? Or is it enough to just update the nameserver information on the new domain host?

EDIT: if it matters, the current registrar is Dreamhost, the target is Gandi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Apps setup generally involves setting up a bunch of DNS resource records.  If you'll be continuing to use the same domain name servers (which would be the case if you were using third-party DNS servers, rather than those provided by your registrar) than you shouldn't need to make any changes.

If you're switching DNS onto new servers, then you'll need to make sure you carry over all of your existing resource records.  Your existing DNS provider should have tools that will let you see all of the records associated with your domain.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a DNS server somewhere, as far as I know Google does not offer DNS services for Apps.  You'll need to find someone that will host DNS for your domain, and then you update DNS to point to Google Apps according to the instructions.  Some domain registrars offer DNS services, Go Daddy has free DNS hosting.

Mark